# Where can I find more themes for VS2012?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

I have downloaded the [VS2012 Theme editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05) but would now like to to find more themes for it. Specifically, I am after .vstheme files, but haven't been able to find any. I'm hoping to get a nice dark theme that works with the theme editor. I am not interested in settings files as used in VS2010. I write in C++ if that is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I found this [site](http://studiostyl.es) to be pretty good with a great mix of themes.
One with actual *.vstheme extension: http://studiostyl.es/schemes/c-dark-scheme-for-use-with-expression-dark-theme

Comment: Why -1? There is an actual theme, matches the asked theme and is strictly to the point? Not the best solution but I don't see anyone with a better one.